# Assigned Leads should not be assigned again for the same user

Tags: javascript, button, plugins, workflow, assign

I have a business scenario of where the leads are generally assigned to a user.
Then, If the same lead(s) are selected again to the same user for whom it has been already assigned, the lead should not get assigned. Instead, it should throw an alert stating that the leads had been assigned already.
As I am new to Sales module, request you all to help me out on this scenario.
Is it possible to achieve thru workflow?
Let me know your suggestions.
Awaiting your response!

Comment: Could you provide some code? The question is hard to answer because it is very broad.

Comment: Hi @mm759 , As I said, i am new to sales module, I am short of doing that. Its pretty simple. Assigned leads should not be assigned to the same user, when assign button is clicked.